# Using if condition for successive states coming across

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I want to print `'double'` when `x` equals `'ok'` two times consecutively in the `while` loop.

My script below:

```py
import random
import time

a = 5

while True:
    b = random.randint(0, 10)
    print(b)
    if a > b:
        x = 'ok'
        print(x)
```

Comment: You need to save the previous result in a variable and compare the current to the previous number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to track your state.

```py
import random
import time

a = 5
prev = False

while True:
    b = random.randint(0, 10)
    print(b)
    if a > b:
        if prev:
            print('double')
        x = 'ok'
        prev = True
    else:
        x = 'ko'
        prev = False
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for a triple version of my question:

```
import random
import time

a = 5
i=0
rec=[]

while True:
    b = random.randint(0, 10)
    print(b)
    if a > b:
        x = 'ok'
        # print(x)
        rec.append(str(x))
        i=i+1
    else:
      x='ko'
      # print(x)
      rec.append(str(x))
      i=i+1
    if i>=3 and (rec[i-1]=='ok' and rec[i-2]=='ok' and rec[i-3]=='ok'):
            print('trible')
    time.sleep(1)
```